# Can't delete ParseObject with owner account

Tags: android, parse-platform, acl

I'm trying to delete a parse object with the following method:

```
object.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e !=null) {
            Log.e("Parse: ",e.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

**Console Output**

> E/Parse:: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Object not
>   found.

My object's ACL is public read and owner read & write and I am connected to the owner account.

The strange thing is that I actually can delete the object if it has public write ACL, but I only want the owner have the possibility to delete it.

Has anyone encountered similar issues ?

Comment: I encountered once this problem, and my mistake was that i actually set the owner only write and not read permissions. Maybe you did the same one

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Already checked, Read and write for the owner on the Parse Dashboard

Comment: @Archipel  What is inside your object is there any json data if it is then mention here your that code where you are insersion data structure of your data ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out that I did something else wrong with my user login which caused this error. Anyways thanks to anybody who tried to help me

Comment: What was the error? I have the exact same problem where a user can only delete their object if the ACL is public write